# SQL: Getting different results when using date conversion function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query that will generates a weekly report

The query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @rundate DATETIME
DECLARE @oneweekago AS DATETIME

SELECT @rundate = getdate() - 2
SELECT @oneweekago = DATEADD(week, -1,@rundate)

SELECT 
    d.date, t2.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3
FROM 
    table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN 
    table3 t3 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON t3.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN 
    table4 t4 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON t4.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN 
    table5 t5 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON t5.num = i.num
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    table6 t6 WITH (NOLOCK)  ON t6.intmid = t1.intmid
WHERE 
    t2.code = '027'
    AND t2.status in('O', 'OPEN', 'P', 'PEND', 'PENDING', 'R', 'REOPEN')
    AND t3.odate BETWEEN @oneweekago AND @rundate
    AND CONVERT(varchar, t3.odate, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, @oneweekago, 101) AND CONVERT(varchar, @rundate, 101)
ORDER BY 
    t1.column1
```

When using

```
CONVERT(varchar, t3.odate, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, @oneweekago, 101) AND CONVERT(varchar, @rundate, 101)
```

the query gives me dates in 2009, 2011, 2010 when I'm only specifying dates for the `04/14/2014 - 04/21/2014` (a week before 2 days ago)

However, when I use

```
t3.odate BETWEEN @oneweekago AND @rundate
```

I'm getting the right results.

What is wrong when using `CONVERT` method?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use that method when the column is a `DATETIME`?

Comment: Also, sorry, can't help but comment about some things. You should **always** use the length of the varchar (`CONVERT(varchar(10),col,101)`), otherwise you can get some nasty surprises. More than that, the format which you are using to convert the dates shouldn't be used with `BETWEEN`; since you are now comparing **strings**, and in this case `04/14/2009` is "bigger" than `04/13/2014`. Finally, if your column has a `time` part, then you should use `BETWEEN` anyway, you could be filtering more results than you think (use an open range instead: >= somedate and < otherdate+1)

Comment: You won't necessarily always get the right result with between OneWeekAgo and RunDate.  With datetimes, a more reliable approach is datefield >= StartDate and datefield < the day after EndDate.

Comment: thank you for the complete explanation

Comment: Oh, my previous comment was meant to say "you **shouldn't** use `BETWEEN` anyway"

Answer (score 0):

You're converting datetime values to varchar, which compare differently. SQL knows how to compare datetime values properly... there's no reason to do a conversion to varchar to do the comparisons. If you need to drop off the time portion, you could do a conversion to get only the date, but then convert that back into a date format before doing your comparison to get the expected results.

Comment: On recent versions of sql server, you can cast datetimes to dates instead of converting back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to a varchar -- converting to a varchar can often give you unexpected results because it isn't treating the dates as if they are dates. It's treating it as a string. Whereas when you simply leave your results as a date it will compare the dates correctly. If you need to drop the time portion you can just convert for date:

```
convert(date, @rundate, 101)
```